# How to copy TableView cell data to a NSMutable Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm quite new to iphone development. I created To-Do List app using coredata. so, my table view dynamically updating.
I want to add table view row textlabels to a NSMutable array (that means row1 text label to 1st index position of MutableArray , row2 text label to 2nd index position of Array)

this is my table view cellfor indexpath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *HeroTableViewCell = @"HeroTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HeroTableViewCell];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:HeroTableViewCell] autorelease];
}
NSManagedObject *oneHero = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSInteger tab = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:tabBar.selectedItem];
switch (tab) {
    case kByName:
        cell.textLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"];
        break;
    case kBySecretIdentity:
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [oneHero valueForKey:@"secretIdentity"];
    default:
        break;
}
//listData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
//if(indexPath.row==1){
    //[listData addObject: cell.textLabel.text];
return cell;
```

}

commented lines are how I'm try to do it, but I struggling to do it as I want
please help me . . .